# Javaでwebアプリを作成。push通知を実装したい

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

開発環境はiOSでエクリプス、javaサーブレット,jspでポートフォリオを作成しております。

先日面接にて私の制作物はプッシュ通知などがなく深みがないと指摘をうけました。
googleで簡単に実装できますと言われたので調べているのですがなかなか参考となるサイトが見つかりません。ある時間になったら通知を送る設定を実装したいのですがどのようにしたら良いでしょうか？参考となる資料などあれば教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「javaサーブレット  websocket」などをキーワードにして検索してみてはいかがですか？